# Asynchronously show up form element

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, ajax

I want to asynchronously show up the price on my form before it gets submitted. I have values saved on an array in a PHP file where the prices will be based on. I formulated the following code based on my research.

HTML

```
<form>
<select id="beds-input-select">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<select id="bath-input-select">
<option value="1.0">1</option><option value="1.5">1.5</option>
<option value="2.0">2</option><option value="2.5">2.5</option>
<option value="3.0">3</option><option value="3.5">3.5</option>
<option value="4.0">4</option><option value="4.5">4.5</option>
<option value="5.0">5</option><option value="5.5">5.5</option>
<option value="6.0">6</option>
</select>

<div id="frequency-options">  
<input type="radio" name="frequency" id="one" checked="checked">
<label for="one">One Time Cleaning</label>

<input type="radio" name="frequency" id="weekly">
<label for="weekly">Weekly Cleaning</label>

<input type="radio" name="frequency" id="biweekly">
<label for="biweekly">Bi-Weekly Cleaning</label>
<input type="radio" name="frequency" id="monthly">
<label for="monthly">Monthly Cleaning</label>
</div>

<h5>Pay Only</h5>
<div class="estimated-price-div">$<span id="estimated-price">0</span></div>
<p><input type="submit" value="Schedule An Appointment Now!" class="estimate-submit"></p>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function updatePrice() {
var bed_select = document.getElementById("beds-input-select");
var bath_select = document.getElementById("bath-input-select");
var frequency_options = document.getElementsByName("frequency");

var estimate_price = document.getElementById("estimated-price");

var bed_id = bed_select.options[bed_select.selectedIndex].value;
var bath_id = bath_select.options[bath_select.selectedIndex].value;
var frequency_id = frequency_options.checked[frequency_options.selectedIndex].value;

var url = 'subcategories.php?selected_bed_id=' + bed_id + '&selected_bath_id=' + bath_id + '&selected_frequency_id' + frequency_id;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        estimate_price.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
xhr.send();
}

var bed_select = document.getElementById("beds-input-select");
bed_select.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);

var bath_select = document.getElementById("bath-input-select");
bath_select.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);

var frequency_options = document.getElementsByName("frequency");
frequency_options.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);
```

PHP

```
$pricing = [
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1 , 'price' => 90],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1.5 , 'price' => 113],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2 , 'price' => 113],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2.5 , 'price' => 135],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 3 , 'price' => 135],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 3.5 , 'price' => 158],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 4 , 'price' => 158],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 4.5 , 'price' => 180],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 5 , 'price' => 180],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 5.5 , 'price' => 203],
['frequency' => one, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 6 , 'price' => 203],

['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1 , 'price' => 81],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1.5 , 'price' => 101],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2 , 'price' => 101],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2.5 , 'price' => 122],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 3 , 'price' => 122],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 3.5 , 'price' => 142],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 4 , 'price' => 142],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 4.5 , 'price' => 162],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 5 , 'price' => 162],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 5.5 , 'price' => 182],
['frequency' => weekly, 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 6 , 'price' => 182]
];

//PASS VALUES from the selected bed_id, bath_id, frequency_id and output $result;

echo $result;
```

How can I use the values selected from the form as used in (var url = 'subcategories.php?selected_bed_id=' + bed_id + '&selected_bath_id=' + bath_id + '&selected_frequency_id' + frequency_id;) to output the result on my HTML Id #estimated-price.

I do not know how to connect my php array with the chosen values. So for example, the user selects VALUE "1" for BEDS, VALUE "2" for BATHS and CHOOSES "WEEKLY" for FREQUENCY, it should OUTPUT PRICE "101". I'm apparently new to PHP and not very familiar with it yet. Can somebody help me on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you use `getElementsByName` you will get an array not a single element. So, I change the code to handle the array as follows:

**Note** your `updatePrice` function is ok. If your `subcategories.php` will return a value, then `updatePrice` will print it out into your `estimate_price` variable.

**Update**
In the function `updatePrice` you are sending a `GET` request. So in your `subcategories.php` file you need to receive those variables using `$_GET`. Then do your calculation and print it out with `echo`.

**Last Update**
Replace the values `one` with `'one'` and `weekly` with `'weekly'` because those are string variables if you use it without `'` php will assume that is a constant.

```
<?php
    $pricing = [
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1 , 'price' => 90],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1.5 , 'price' => 113],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2 , 'price' => 113],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2.5 , 'price' => 135],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 3 , 'price' => 135],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 3.5 , 'price' => 158],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 4 , 'price' => 158],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 4.5 , 'price' => 180],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 5 , 'price' => 180],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 5.5 , 'price' => 203],
    ['frequency' => 'one', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 6 , 'price' => 203],

    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1 , 'price' => 81],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1.5 , 'price' => 101],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2 , 'price' => 101],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2.5 , 'price' => 122],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 3 , 'price' => 122],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 3.5 , 'price' => 142],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 4 , 'price' => 142],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 4.5 , 'price' => 162],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 5 , 'price' => 162],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 5.5 , 'price' => 182],
    ['frequency' => 'weekly', 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 6 , 'price' => 182]
    ];

    if( $_GET['selected_bed_id'] && $_GET['selected_bath_id'] && $_GET['selected_frequency_id']) {

        $selected_bed_id = $_GET['selected_bed_id'];
        $selected_bath_id = $_GET['selected_bath_id'];
        $selected_frequency_id = $_GET['selected_frequency_id'];

        foreach( $pricing as $element ) {
            if( $element['frequency'] == $selected_frequency_id && 
            $element['beds'] == $selected_bed_id && 
            $element['baths'] == $selected_bath_id) {
                echo $element['price'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

```js
var bed_select = document.getElementById("beds-input-select");
bed_select.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);

var bath_select = document.getElementById("bath-input-select");
bath_select.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);

var frequency_options = document.getElementsByName("frequency");
frequency_options.forEach(function(element) {
  // console.log(element);
  element.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);
});

function updatePrice() {
  var estimate_price = document.getElementById("estimated-price");

  var bed_id = bed_select.options[bed_select.selectedIndex].value;
  var bath_id = bath_select.options[bath_select.selectedIndex].value;

  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
  var frequency_id = radios.length > 0 ? radios[0].id : null;

  var url = 'subcategories.php?selected_bed_id=' + bed_id + '&selected_bath_id=' + bath_id + '&selected_frequency_id=' + frequency_id;
  
  alert(
  'selected_bed_id=' + bed_id + '\n'+
  'selected_bath_id=' + bath_id + '\n'+
  'selected_frequency_id=' + frequency_id + '\n');

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      estimate_price.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="beds-input-select">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>

  <select id="bath-input-select">
<option value="1.0">1</option><option value="1.5">1.5</option>
<option value="2.0">2</option><option value="2.5">2.5</option>
<option value="3.0">3</option><option value="3.5">3.5</option>
<option value="4.0">4</option><option value="4.5">4.5</option>
<option value="5.0">5</option><option value="5.5">5.5</option>
<option value="6.0">6</option>
</select>

  <div id="frequency-options">
    <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="one" checked="checked">
    <label for="one">One Time Cleaning</label>

    <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="weekly">
    <label for="weekly">Weekly Cleaning</label>

    <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="biweekly">
    <label for="biweekly">Bi-Weekly Cleaning</label>
    <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="monthly">
    <label for="monthly">Monthly Cleaning</label>
  </div>

  <h5>Pay Only</h5>
  <div class="estimated-price-div">$<span id="estimated-price">0</span></div>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Schedule An Appointment Now!" class="estimate-submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: How about the php array? How do I get to filter the options and output the price?

Comment: your updatePrice function is ok. If your subcategories.php will return a value, then updatePrice will print it out into your estimate_price variable.
You didn't how your php function. I cannot modify your php code because you didn't show us.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently that was my main question as I am still a newbie  And not very familiar with PHP. I have been looking for ways on how to initialize the values on PHP that will become the equivalent of the selections on my form. I'd like to see how those values can be returned as the price by using a PHP function. Thanks again!

Comment: show me your `subcategories.php` file anything that you have there. The idea is that we will provide a solution based on your implementation.

Comment: I put an example for your `subcategories` file

Comment: The PHP portion is the only code i have for my php file. The array part only T_T

Comment: OK I will make also the array search for you~! only for this time.

Comment: This is the last update. Contains the JavaScript correction and the PHP handler for the GET request.

Comment: Omg! You're such a life-saver! Thank you so much!